# Mock fetching Airflow variables from AWS SSM parameter store

Tags: unit-testing, airflow, pytest, aws-ssm

I have stored my key-val pairs in an AWS SSM parameter store for example:

"a/b/c": "true",
"a/b/d": "test"

In my Airflow code, I have

```
key1 = Variable.get('a/b/c')
key2 = Variable.get('a/b/d')
```

Now when I write my unit test, how should I mock this?

I tried a couple of ways like using `AIRFLOW_VAR_xxx` but none of them work.

Comment: You can create `Variables` using `Variable.set`. Does that work?

Comment: @samJ, yes I did, so I tried to add 
`test_key1 = Variable.set('a/b/c', 'test')`
Still I got the error `E   KeyError: 'Variable a/b/c does not exist'`, which leads me to try monkeypatch or mock.patch.dict(), but none worked.

Comment: You don't need to assign the output of `Variable.set` to a new variable. `Variable.set` is enough on its own.

Comment: I got the same error when I have `Variable.set('a/b/c', 'test')`.  I am wondering if it is because I run the test in a docker container, there is no actual connection to airflow backend and that is where it complains?

Comment: AIRFLOW_VAR_xxx should work. It possible you are not setting the environment variable in the correct place. What happens if you `print(os.environ)` before calling `Variable.get`?

Comment: @0x26res, actually that is the first method I tried, the variables are stored in AWS SSM parameter store instead of the Variables on airflow, and it is in the format of 'a/b/c', so when I tried to do AIRFLOW_VAR_a/b/c it cannot work. I also found in the source code, airflow would search for variables in SSM and I tried variations like AIRFLOW_VAR_c etc, and none worked. Hmm, that does not print anything for me.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use `/` in your variable. There is possibly a way to escape them but that's not well documented in airflow's doc. Also you mention you use docker, so how do you set the environment variables? Are you able to actually set any environment variable (eg: `FOO=BAR`) and see it in airflow using `print(os.environ)`

Comment: @0x26res, thank you! I actually figured out so I use monkeypatch and it actually works. Earlier when it didn't work, because I had a global import and this import happens before the mock, so no matter what I have for mock, it does not work.